# None of the SSH connection options are working

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

There seems to be no option to connect to a compute engine instance using SSH.

Here's what I've already tried:

**Cloud Console In-browser SSH**

Error:

```
The VM guest environment is outdated and only supports the deprecated 'sshKeys' metadata item.
```

**Cloud Shell using GCloud command**

Command:

```
$ gcloud compute --project "reflective-data" ssh --zone "us-central1-a" "instance-1"
```

Error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

**Google Cloud SDK Shell**

Command:

```
$ gcloud compute --project "reflective-data" ssh --zone "us-central1-a" "instance-1"
```

Error:

```
[PuTTY Fatal Eroor] Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
```

---

After all of these failed, I also tried deleting all ssh-keys for the instance and later also for the project. The errors remain the same.

Firewall settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a separate SSH key pair, and then edit the GCE instance's metadata to add the public key (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only) and then try the connection again?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method that has worked for me:

## Windows / PuTTY

1. Open PuTTYgen
2. Click start
3. Create randomness, by moving your mouse
4. For the key comment type in the username of your VM
5. Click Save Private Key (end the file name in .ppk)
6. Click Save Public Key (end the file name in .pub)
7. Back in Google Cloud's Console: Click on your instance name
8. Click 'Edit'
9. Scroll down to 'SSH'
10. Where it says "enter entire key data: Paste
11. Save

## Mac / Terminal

### Create the SSH Key

In the terminal type `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/{filename} -C {username}`

Upload the Public Key to your VM

1. In the terminal type `cat ~/.ssh/{filename}.pub`
2. Copy the results to the clipboard
3. Back in Google Cloud's Console: Click on your instance name
4. Click 'Edit'
5. Scroll down to 'SSH'
6. Where it says "enter entire key data: Paste
7. Save